# Trying to reference a environment variable defined on the virtual host

Tags: symfony

I have just added an environment variable to my virutal host, and add a reference to it in `parameters.yml`. But when I clear the cache I get this:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
>   You have requested a non-existent parameter "email.password". Did you
>   mean this: "mailer_password"?

```
# parameters.yml
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: domain
    database_user: root
    database_password: *****
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host: ~
    mailer_user: domain@gmail.com
    mailer_password: %email.password%
    secret: *****

#virtual host
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/sedigital/domain/web
        DirectoryIndex app.php
     SetEnv SYMFONY__EMAIL__PASSWORD "*****"
    <Directory /home/sedigital/domain/web/>
        # Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        #Order allow,deny
        #allow from all
        Require all granted
        FallbackResource /index.php
        # BEGIN EXPIRES
        <IfModule mod_expires.c>
            ExpiresActive On
            ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
            ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
            ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
            ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
        </IfModule>
        # END EXPIRES
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have run also: `$ export SYMFONY__EMAIL__PASSWORD=*****`

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache 2.4.7

**EDIT:** Finally it is working, maybe I forgot to restart Apache after `$ export SYMFONY__EMAIL__PASSWORD=*****`.

Comment: Did you restarted apache?

Comment: @RyanVincent sorry, I didn' understand the question, sorry because my english. I just defined `email.password` at my virtualhost and then using `$ export SYMFONY__EMAIL__PASSWORD=***** `

Comment: @RyanVincent http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html

Comment: Have you tried to remove the line `mailer_password: %email.password%` and do the   `SetEnv SYMFONY__MAILER_PASSWORD "*****"`?